# Babel - French - Exact definitions of the macros \og and \fg

Tags: babel-french

I would like to mimic exactly the behavior of the quotes `\og` and `\fg` proposed by babel when french is the main language.

What should I do because the following code is wrong?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel, varioref} % Comment this line
                                     % test when babel
                                     % is not loaded.

\providecommand\og{{\leavevmode\raise0.25ex\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\ll$}}\,}

\providecommand\fg{\,{\raise0.25ex\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\gg$}}}


\begin{document}

\og ABCD \fg{} et \og EFGH \fg{}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you *really* want to use `\ll` and `\gg` as replacement for guillemets? Oh, no! Use the real thing from the T1 encoding.

Comment: That's our typographical rules... ;-) Do you have a better solution?

Comment: I think he's suggesting that you use « and » in place of ≪ and ≫

Comment: The code "comes" from `babel` sources.

Comment: Yeah, those definitions are all over the place and they're pretty 

Comment: @projetmbc Do you mean that the French typographic rules prescribe the symbols on the left in [this picture (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NF9i.png)? I thought something like the glyphs on the right are used.

Comment: I just follow `babel`'s choices. For my part, I prefer to use `"..."`. ;-) Can someone explain to me why my spacing is wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `french.ldf` package indeed does

```
    \def\guillemotleft{\leavevmode\raise0.25ex
                       \hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\ll$}}
    \def\guillemotright{\raise0.25ex
                        \hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\gg$}}
```

at some point. But this is just to provide something that might resemble *guillemets* when the real thing is not available. Actually, this is even not used, because `babel` takes over and does

```
\ProvideTextCommand{\guillemotleft}{OT1}{%
  \ifmmode
    \ll
  \else
    \save@sf@q{\nobreak
      \raise.2ex\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\ll$}\bbl@allowhyphens}%
  \fi}
\ProvideTextCommand{\guillemotright}{OT1}{%
  \ifmmode
    \gg
  \else
    \save@sf@q{\nobreak
      \raise.2ex\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\gg$}\bbl@allowhyphens}%
  \fi}
```

which explains why your document typesets as

[image]

Note that your `\providecommand` instructions do nothing at all, because the commands *are* defined when `babel-french` is used.

In the following picture you can compare the result from that definition and the **real** *guillemets* in the Computer Modern font

[image]

No document should use the hacked glyphs on the left instead of the real *guillemets*. In order to typeset French you ***need*** a T1 encoded font.

Anyway, if you want to pursue bad typography, you should consider that left *guillemets* need to be followed by an *espace insécable* (i.e. a non-breaking space), while right *guillemets* have to be preceded by one. And an *espace insécable* is a different thing than the thin space produced by `\,`. So, if you want to provide the horrible thing when `babel-french` is not loaded and the font is not T1 encoded, do as follows.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\providecommand\og{%
  \raisebox{0.25ex}{$\scriptscriptstyle\ll$}%
  ~% unbreakable space
  \ignorespaces % ignore following spaces
}
\makeatletter
\providecommand\fg{%
  \leavevmode@ifvmode
  \unskip % ignore a preceding space
  ~% non-breaking space
  \raisebox{0.25ex}{$\scriptscriptstyle\gg$}%
}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\og ABCD \fg{} et \og EFGH \fg{}.

\end{document}
```

But, please, don't.

Comment: For the `\providecommand`, I use it intensionally to test the difference of the outputs by simply comment or not the import of `babel`. I will test carefully your solution tomorrow. Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: My "ugly" macros are just here in case of degraded use of a package of mine: this allows some macros to always work and a warning will tell to the user to load `babel` in case this has not been done.